# ActionFunction reloads the page even I have a reRender and returns null

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

My `<apex:actionFunction>` keeps reloading the VF page even though it does have a reRender attribute and the controller method returns null. Below are part of my code:

**Markup:**

```
<apex:pageMessages id="page_message" />
<apex:actionFunction name="testConnection"  action="{!testConnection}" reRender="page_message" onComplete="displayConnectionInfo();" />
```

**onComplete function:**

```
function displayConnectionInfo() {
    $(".slds-spinner_container").hide();
    overridePageMessages();
    return false;
}
```

**Controller method:**

```
public pageReference testConnection() 
{
    ApexPages.Message connection_info = Util.testConnection();

    ApexPages.addMessage(connection_info);
    return null;
}
```

My another page has a similar button and actionfunction and does work very well without reloading the page. There must be something I missed here but I am not sure what is it.

Comment: two question from where you are calling this `actionfunction` and `overridePageMessages();` what this function do?

Comment: @TusharSharma testConnection basically test connection between Salesforce and our system. overridePageMessages() simply converts `<apex:pageMessages>` into lds style. I assure you there is no page loading code in Javascript. I have double checked.

Comment: Can you just comment overridePageMessages(); and try.

Comment: @Reshma Just tried. Still refresh. It doesn't even go into the onComplete method when I debug

Comment: I just tried with commandButton version and it works fine or me without page reloading. However, still not sure why actionFunction still reloads the page. @sfdcfox , not sure whether you got some idea on this?

Comment: I tested your code and it is working for me. I think something else is triggering causing the page refresh.

Comment: @SarojBera It could and should be. But I am just wondering which can be the potential reason? It is working in the command button but not in the actionFunction with approximate same code.

Comment: Shot in the dark. Have you tried returning true? Not that it matters but why the PR return of the method. Just make it void unless you actually expect to return a PR of course

Comment: @Eric I have tried all these but nothing works. I am giving up to use the commandButton way. Will come back to this issue once I got some time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @LanceShi - How are you executing the actionFunction? via script, button, link?

Comment: @Eric via a button. Ah... I got it now. I was simply stupid! I didn't specify the button type so it defaults to submit!

Comment: @LanceShi - Yup - Thats what I was going to post if you said button.....Yor Minimal Reproducible Example was a bit too minimal :)

Comment: @Eric what does MVR stands for?

Comment: @LanceShi - Typo - fixed it for ya

Comment: @Eric thanks for that. I didn't realize the issue before you pointed out!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using commandButton and using Onclick function so please make sure to use "return false" inside Onclick function.